# HP NC364T on CentOS 7

Tags: hp, nic, centos7

i am trying to install a quad port network card (HP NC364T) into a machine I have running CentOS 7. The issue is that during boot, the OS hard crashes and reboots the machine. This is after all boot messages and occasionally after logging in to the OS.

I have attempted to find a compatible RedHat driver from the HP website but it appears none are compatible with this OS, or at least they all fail to install, none getting past 'resolving dependencies'. (This is with the card not in the machine as the system is unusable with it installed, just loops through boot-up and hard crash over and over.)

I have also tried the recovery module bot it crashes the same way.

So, this may be 1) impossible and I should stop trying, 2) very easy and I just need to get the right driver repository or 3) something complicated and requires more information.

Simple question: how can I debug the operating system crashes to see exactly what the issue is? Ultimate questions: is this possible and how do I do it?

I am relatively new to Linux (have a DOS/Windows background) and realise there will be a steep learning curve but this is tough. Any pointers/help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of server is this? Make, model, generation.

Comment: It is a small business server based on commodity desktop hardware, not server grade yet.

Comment: I'll go with option 1.

Comment: @joeqwerty Why do you say?

Comment: You _might_ get this to work, but I wouldn't bet the business on it!

Comment: `based on commodity desktop hardware` ... and this is exactly why IT professionals prefer OEM platforms over whitebox frankenservers.  You build it yourself, you have to work through these issues on your own.  You buy an HP or a Dell or an IBM (etc.), you call them up and make them fix the problem.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because it prominently involves software or hardware that is not what is generally considered “professional grade” and may itself be causing the problem, or actively hindering a repeatable and consistent solution.

Comment: @Wesley I could try pushing this to SuperUser however the people in this forum likely have a lot more experience and knowledge on the topic. I'd like to think there is a forum for the use of commodity hardware on StackExchange, where if not straightforward answers are offered, at least perfessional-level and robust problem solving techniques are offered.